# In Node.js better store reference to whole object or just parts

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my work I often need to store objects grouped by properties, e.g. if I have

```
obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, ... },
obj2 = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, ... }
...
```

then I need to have groups like

```
obj_by_a = { 1: obj1, 2: obj2, ... }
```

But usually I don't need all properties, for example, I may need only `b`:

```
obj_by_a = { 1: { b: 2 }, 2: { b: 3 } }
```

However, as I understand, if I set `obj_by_a[1] = obj1` it wouldn't actually make a copy of `obj1`, but rather store a reference to it. So probably, from point of view of memory and performance, it would be better to store the whole object anyway, not create a new one as in `obj_by_a[1] = { b: obj1.b }`.

Is this correct?

Comment: Probably true. However, having objects with less properties means you will have a better worse-case performance. It won't affect the average one, though.

Comment: You should use an array instead for this case

Comment: yes, the ref will use less ram than small new object would

Comment: @Svenskunganka could you explain in more details?

Comment: Like this: `[ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 } ]`. You can then iterate over your objects a whole lot easier by using `Array.forEach` or `arr[0]` which in this case is the object  `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`. If you come from a PHP background this can be a little hard to understand because in PHP an array is the equivalent of an Javascript object and array combined.

Comment: @Svenskunganka if I need to go through objects frequently, I think from point of view of performance, it would be easier to build an "index" like `obj_by_a` once and then reuse it.

Comment: @Oriol in this case what would be the "worse-case" performance ?

Comment: Storing a reference to the desired array element index would be much more lightweight. Your example code is _really_ bad, I don't fully comprehend what you are trying to do here. Please update your post with real data and examples of your current implementation.

Comment: @xaxa In a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), searches, insertions and deletions have a O(n) worst case and O(1) average case; where n is the number of keys.

Comment: @Svenskunganka, full example would be a lot of soc, so I better try to explain. Usually problem arises when I perform a few queries to database and get results `db_1_res`, `db_2_res`, ... then I make an array or an object of objects, each containing some fields from each query result: `var t = []; t.push({ name: db_1_res[i].name, city: db_2_res[j].city });` For example, I may need to prepare data for a table in view template. My question is: would it be better to store the whole objects, not individual fields: `t.push({ res_1: db_1_res[i], res_2: db_2_res[j] });`, then use as `t[i].res_1.name`

Comment: @Svenskunganka I prefer using object of objects because usually there is some unifying `id` throughout these tables, like `person_id` and you may have `var t={}; t[person_id] = { ... }`. It is much better imho to have an object whose keys are these `id`s, so it is in some sense already indexed. Otherwise to get a particular element I would always need to run `filter()`, or create and pass around another object whose values are indexes of the array. (as you said).